# WPF 4+ software rendering still an issue?

Tags: wpf

In earlier versions of WPF setting Window.AllowsTransparency or using BitmapEffects (the deprecated ones), or TileBrush usage, apparently could cause WPF to switch to a software rendering mode instead of hardware rendering thus affecting performance dramatically.

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx) list, but it is from 2010.

Are there any potentially common cases that could cause software rendering to occur in framework 4+? Assume the hardware is sufficient, purely software related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This list is still accurate.

This is covered on MSDN's page regarding Graphics Rendering Tiers.  The second labeled as "The following features and capabilities are not hardware accelerated:" lists the specific criteria that can cause non-accellerated rendering in WPF.

This includes:

- `TileBrush`
- Content rendered via `RenderTargetBitmap`
- Any printed output
- Surfaces exceeding the graphics hardware's maximum texture size
- Layered windows on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post by Dwayne Need seems to suggest that **layered windows on Windows XP now *are* hardware accelerated**.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx

> DirectX does provide the IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC method, which can
>   return a DC that references the DirectX surface.  Unfortunately there
>   was a restriction in DX9c that would fail this method if it were
>   called on a surface that contained an alpha channel.  Of course, the
>   entire point of our layered window API is to enable per-pixel
>   transparency.  This restriction was lifted for Vista, but our initial
>   release forced WPF to use its software rendering fallback with
>   rendering to a layered window on XP.  We were able to lift this
>   restriction for XP too, which we released as a hot fix (KB 937106). 
>   This hot fix was also included in XP SP3, so go get it!  Now, on XP,
>   we can render via DirectX and pass the results of
>   IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC directly to UpdateLayeredWindow.  On good
>   video drivers, the resulting copy will remain entirely on the video
>   card, leading to excellent performance.  Some video drivers, however,
>   may choose to perform this copy through system memory.  The
>   performance on such systems will not be nearly as good, but should
>   still be reasonable for many scenarios.

I tested this out by running the Perforator tool of the WPF Performance Suite (and checking the check box titled 'Draw software rendering with a purple tint') ... on a layered window application ... and everything seemed to be hardware accelerated (no purple tinting).

The recent MSDN documentation on [Graphics Rendering Tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196(v=vs.110).aspx) still says (as Reed Copsey points out) that it should be software rendered, but that is not what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Ha! I just found this StackOverflow [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576016/is-wpf-hardware-accelerated-when-window-allowstransparency-true) ... which confirms what I am seeing.